# ajax fade in or fade out effect, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a way to show simple fade in or fade out effect in ajax and make it pretty with a color or background color, but without jQuery, because jQuery is not suitable for small web pages and it's too heavy for poor connections!

I need a function which I can use when OnReadyStat becomes 4, or xmlhttp.status is equal to 200, then show the result with a simple effect.

I think Microsoft DXImageTransform can help me, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: http://webdev.proweblog.com/archives/2009/11/06/31/ seems to be what you are after

Comment: Not suitable for small web pages? Too heavy for poor connections? Where are you hearing this?

Comment: jQuery min is 32kb. Is that too large for your purposes vahid?

Comment: but smaller jQuery library i saw until now, is more than 50kb! where did you take 32kb?? please put download link.

Comment: http://jquery.com/ : "(32KB, Minified and Gzipped)". If correctly configured your server sends this file gzipped.

Comment: If your target market is rural Africa, South America, or Asia, then I would avoid jQuery at all costs.  If they might visit other sites with jQurey (like here on SO) & they are using a public CDN (like http://ajax.googleapis.com/...), then you can link the same file on your HTML, & if they have visted that CDN version before, the browser will use that cached version & not download it.  EG the file SO uses is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js, which is also linked by many other sites.

Answer (score 1):

http://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+javascript+opacity+fade

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation

http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Cross-Browser-CSS-Opacity-and-the-JavaScript-Fade-Fading-Effect

Ensure you get all the browser-prefixes correct.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is perfect for any web page!! I would suggest you go with jQuery. Where did you hear it is not suitable for web pages or heavy for poor connections. Go with jQuery.